# How to get the size of the sidebar from a VSCode extension?

Tags: vscode-extensions

We're trying to get the size (width) of the SideBar programmatically in our VSCode extension, how can we do that?
Thanks

We tried getting it from the `vscode` object but couldn't find anything there.

Comment: You probably can't. [Access to the DOM is not available for extensions.](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/9963) This is related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66171832/3784008