# How can I force the VS Code panel to be certain height on startup?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, window

I think the title and image sum up the problem (this has been going on for years).

Any way to force the terminal window to have a fixed height (or percentage, e.g. 15%) when launching/restarting VSCode?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any `terminal.integrated` settings set in your setting.json file? Or `workbench.panel` settings?

Comment: @TimothyG. worbench.panel OpenMaximized is set to Preserve. I have several terminal.integrated sub configurations, but none seem relevant to the problem at hand. After disabling altClickMovesCursor and restating VSCode all terminals defaulted to ~20% of the window height. Not sure what to make of this, especially since I re-enabled altClickMovesCursor, changed terminal window height, restarted, and the terminal windows on all VSCode instances got reset to ~20%. Maybe it's something that will come up again after a restart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VS Code stores the workbench panel size memory in `globalStorage/state.vscdb` under [the same directory as user settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations). You can open the database file with `sqlite3` and then run `UPDATE ItemTable SET value = 123 WHERE key = 'workbench.panel.size';`. If you're interested in the primary sidebar or the secondary/auxiliary sidebar, see also the `workbench.sidebar.size` and `workbench.auxiliarybar.size` keys.

Then you could write a shell script that does that modification and then runs `code` and passes the rest of the script arguments to `code`. Ex. in Bash ([you need to do some singlequote dances](/q/1250079/11107541)), the command to do the DB modification would be (using `100` as an example value): `sqlite3 ~/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb 'UPDATE ItemTable SET value = 100 WHERE key = '"'"'workbench.panel.size'"'"';'`

See also [How can I configure the sidebar and panel's default sizes in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66171832/11107541).

Other keys related to the panel include `workbench.panel.wasLastMaximized`, `workbench.panel.position`, `workbench.panel.hidden`, `workbench.panelpart.activepanelid`, and others.

Comment: I though VSCode remembers each instance's panel height, but now I see there's just a single entry in that DB for `workbench.panel.size` and that it changes when quitting VSCode, probably according to the instance that terminated last. This is a bit of a hack as it should've been exposed as a VSCode setting, but a good enough hack for me. @starball you got my vote. Thank you.